# Aggregating finer raster data to 25-km grid using a point shapefile

Tags: r, aggregate, raster, shapefile

I have a series of lat long from a point shapefile which is 25-km grid

```
lon <- c(-53.615449969, -53.365449969, -53.115449969, -53.365449969, 
         -53.115449969, -52.865449969, -53.365449969, -53.115449969, -52.865449969, 
         -52.615449969, -53.365449969, -53.115449969, -52.865449969, -52.615449969, 
         -52.365449969, -53.365449969, -53.115449969, -52.865449969, -52.615449969, 
         -52.365449969, -53.615449969, -53.365449969, -53.115449969, -52.865449969, 
         -52.615449969, -52.365449969, -52.115449969, -53.865449969, -53.615449969, 
         -53.365449969, -53.115449969, -52.865449969, -52.615449969, -52.365449969, 
         -52.115449969, -51.865449969, -54.365449969, -54.115449969, -53.865449969, 
         -53.615449969, -53.365449969, -53.115449969, -52.865449969, -52.615449969, 
         -52.365449969, -52.115449969, -51.865449969, -51.615449969, -54.615449969, 
         -54.365449969, -54.115449969, -53.865449969, -53.615449969, -53.365449969, 
         -53.115449969, -52.865449969, -52.615449969, -52.365449969, -52.115449969, 
         -51.615449969)


lat <- c(-33.627081271, -33.627081271, -33.627081271, -33.377081271, 
         -33.377081271, -33.377081271, -33.127081271, -33.127081271, -33.127081271, 
         -33.127081271, -32.877081271, -32.877081271, -32.877081271, -32.877081271, 
         -32.877081271, -32.627081271, -32.627081271, -32.627081271, -32.627081271, 
         -32.627081271, -32.377081271, -32.377081271, -32.377081271, -32.377081271, 
         -32.377081271, -32.377081271, -32.377081271, -32.127081271, -32.127081271, 
         -32.127081271, -32.127081271, -32.127081271, -32.127081271, -32.127081271, 
         -32.127081271, -32.127081271, -31.877081271, -31.877081271, -31.877081271, 
         -31.877081271, -31.877081271, -31.877081271, -31.877081271, -31.877081271, 
         -31.877081271, -31.877081271, -31.877081271, -31.877081271, -31.627081271, 
         -31.627081271, -31.627081271, -31.627081271, -31.627081271, -31.627081271, 
         -31.627081271, -31.627081271, -31.627081271, -31.627081271, -31.627081271, 
        -31.627081271)

  df <- as.data.frame(cbind(lon, lat))
  df$ID <- 1:nrow(df)
  coordinates(df) <- c(1,2)
  plot(df, pch = 0)
```

[image]

Why are the squares not touching each other? I thought if this is a 25-km grid, all the squares should be sharing their respective boundaries.

Comment: I've edited this down to one question - answer below shortly.

Comment: Okay. My second part which has been edited out was about how to aggregate the finer elevation data for each 25-km grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've created is a SpatialPointsDataFrame - when you `plot` it, you get markers centred at the points. Using `pch=0` uses a square marker, but it has no idea of the data being a regular grid. You can plot the marker with different sizes - try:

```
plot(df, pch = 0, cex=6)
plot(df, pch = 0, cex=0.5)
```

or with a different marker:

```
plot(df, pch="Z")
```

Comment: Okay. My second part which has been edited out was about how to aggregate the finer elevation data for each 25-km grid.

Comment: That's a separate question - create a new question for that.